# HOW CAN I FIX THIS ERROR? (ANDROID STUDIO KOTLİN)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

1. 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BU�LD FAILED in 1s
23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
2)
The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
3)
Failed to compile values file.

Comment: are you using any other dependency??

Comment: `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0` Did you recently upgrade gradle? If so, switch back to the old version.